# Should I use a CMS or not for an ecommerce website

Tags: content-management-system, web, web-frameworks

Say I am required to build an E-Commerce website that could eventually become very very large. The site would start with at least 100,000 different products, and would include features like Amazon. Would you advise me to use a CMS? or to build this website from ground up?

Something to take into consideration is that if I use a CMS, there would still need to be lots of custom coding, since we want many features not commonly available.

Taking into consideration factors such as Speed, Security and Scalability.

Features would include: Different sets of details for different products, product comparisons, reviews, customer management, customer points system, and all the basic ecommerce features.

If you say CMS, Can you also suggest CMS's that would be great for this kind of store.

Thank you.

Comment: Open-ended (OT). Of course, no sense re-inventing the wheel when there are already *so many specialized products* out there.

Comment: OK, but would it be feasible? I mean since we would still need to implement a whole lot of other features. And how would CMS's handle scalability to say 1 million products? and millions of daily hits?

Comment: Everyone will have their own opinion. What matters is wether you are competent to write something like this. If not you're just soliciting opinions on products and that's not what this site is about.

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon No. Of course not. All Content Management Systems are generic kid-toys written in PHP by script kiddies and are incapable of scaling or handling large inventory systems <-- false statement. (The very term "CMS" has a broad scope and encompasses *many* platforms.)

Comment: We can build something like this. However, we don't want to re-implement the wheel. But at the same time, we don't want to use a CMS and run into problems later on. So thats where your advise comes in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have to consider many things. in general means,  using CMS is good idea.It reduce development time as well as development cost. But you may need to make modifications on source code in order to gain what exactly you want from it. On the other hand build such application from scratch allows you to obtain exactly what you want. but its will takes time as well as much cost.
follow through bellow link
http://www.mykeblack.com/web-design/how-much-does-an-ecom-website-cost

and also if you choose an FOSS CMS find something has higher community involvement as well as support.

If you use paypal as payment method , check their web site. they suggest couple of good commercial CMS.

Comment: Thank you for the ans. Magneto's monthly cost is $125 for 10000 SKU's. This site will have over 100000 SKU's. So the monthly cost would be an issue here. This is a really hard decision...

Answer (score 1):

The ideal e-commerce solution for that volume would be [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)

The only downfall is that its very robust and has a steep learning curve. I do NOT recommend using a framework that is a blogging site first, with an e-commerce plugin or add-on such as WordPress. It will not be able to support the traffic, the product volume, or the security precautions that should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously is better if you use a CMS, I recommend you [OpenCart](http://opencart.com) if you just want to do an E-Commerce web site, it's is so simple and Open Source. 
For something bigger you can try [Joomla](http://joomla.org) as CMS and a great extension called VirtueMart (http://virtuemart.net)[3], it's very complete an extensible..

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use pre-made code, you are at the mercy of the features included.  Adding features can be significantly harder than with custom code.

That having been said, it is definitely not unheard of to START your site with pre-made code (or even a whole platform - like selling via Amazon) and only the included features so you can start making *revenue* while you write your own solution.